# How to calculate frequency of an AC source with variable frequency using Arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage, ac, frequency, measurement

I have an AC current source. Its properties are

1. Maximum Vrms=15v
2. Maximum Frequency 125 Hz
3. Minimum Frequency 5 Hz
4. The current source is pickup coil of a motorcycle... Vrms range is approximately 0.7v-15v

My Objective: At any particular time, I want to know the frequency of the AC source as it can vary randomly.

The below image shows, voltage vs time graph of the AC source at 125 Hz. [This is an approximation and Time is in second unit.  ]

[image: Approximate sample at 125Hz]

I couldn't find a way to approach this problem. A little help, may be suggestion of a sensor or any possible way, is very much required.

Comment: A sine lookup table and analogWrite?

Comment: Have you investigated how ac voltmeters and frequency counters work? This is not a novel measurement. Also, you need to tells your requirements for accuracy and measurement time.

Comment: My requirement is: detecting 1 frequency at each 0.008 second

Comment: For a signal with period of 200ms, you likely can't detect the frequency every 8ms.

Comment: this may help https://duckduckgo.com/?q=zero+crossing+detector&ia=web

Comment: A current source might have harmonics for some loads.  Don't you have you any better specs? or moving parts?

Comment: the current source is pickup coil of a motorcycle

Comment: _"**Maximum** Vrms=15v... frequency of the AC source... can vary randomely"_ - can the voltage also vary 'randomly' or is it stable?

Comment: As @Justme pointed out, you can take samples for 200 ms (1/5 Hz) every 4ms (1/(2*125 Hz)) samples. Then apply a DFT/FFT software (some ms for 50 points). So, the "answer" could be, at best, every "second" ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Not really, because if you for example measure time between two positive zero crossings, you get a new measurement for each period of sine wave, so every 8 to 200 milliseconds.

Comment: @Justme  Yes. Right for that "simple" way, If there are no harmonics and/or "multiple" zero crossings, as pointed by Tony Stewart EE75. From where come this "current" sine source?

Comment: @Antonio51 Since it is used for motocycle RPM detection, the problems of interfacing electronically to such signals and measuring their frequency have been solved long ago.

Comment: @BruceAbbott yes it varies. Vrms range is approximately 0.7v-15v

Comment: @Justme Agree. I did some "devices" in the years 70th (electronic starter and counter for gasoline cars & motorcycles :-) In fact, I am more interested in "survey" systems which can detect some "malfunctions" in "real time" when these "things" are "running" ...

Comment: _"the current source is pickup coil of a motorcycle... Vrms range is approximately 0.7v-15v"_ - please put that information in the question.

Comment: I have created a frequency measuring circuit with optocoupler and Arduino. But a 60Hz signal will be showed 58 or 65 or 70 or even upto 85 Hz. 
My circuit diagram is in this link. https://imgur.com/a/gPQBg0k 
I have also used interupt.. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Minimum Frequency 5 Hz
>
> detecting 1 frequency at each 0.008 second

If these are both true, you've ruled out the simplest options already, as you can't wait for events from a zero-cross detector on their own.

One light-weight solution involves still using a ZCD, and applying a simple, linear extrapolation filter after the ZCD to guess what the current frequency is based on the previous two periods and the amount of elapsed time. This would not require a LUT.

For the heavy-weight solution, you will need a DSP with a very careful filter to normalise your magnitude, eliminate harmonics and estimate your frequency. Depending on how accurate you need this and how complex the resulting DSP is, this will stretch or exceed the capabilities of an Arduino.

It's also worth noting that any pickup from an automotive motor is an excellent recipe to fry a microcontroller unless you thoroughly protect the circuit - clamp, optoisolate, etc.

Comment: Arduino's interrupt works in micros second. Then why I can't detect zero crossing after each 8 milliseconds?

Comment: @AshiqurRahmanNayeem Because zero crossing events may be as slow as _two hundred milliseconds_ apart.

Comment: But the event still occurs. So where is the problem detecting it? I may be failing to get your point. Anyways, how is professional frequency measuring devices are made the if all these  parameters are there?